# Separating gold and silver from gold foil using hydrochloric acid and hydrogen peroxide

Tags: solubility

I used  $\ce{HCl}$ and $\ce{H2O2}$ to recover gold foils by dissolving all other metals. My solution I assume contains a large amount of silver. How do I drop the silver out of the  $\ce{HCl}$  and peroxide solution.)

Answer (score 2):

Hot oxidizing acids, such as nitric acid od sulfuric acid, are the more canonical methods to separate gold from less rare metals.

> > My solution I assume contains a large amount of silver.

If so, shouldn't you have noticed a precipitate of silver chloride ($\ce{AgCl}$) under these conditions?

Answer (score 0):

I would have used aqua regia but was trying to leave the foils solid. I should have used just nitric acid.I would hate to waste the dissolved metals in the HCL. Wanted to recover the silver and copper.Am I correct to assume if I added the nitric acid the silver chloride would participate.

Comment: Probably not since the silver is dissolved as $AgCl_2^-$.